# Node webkit, access to "unsafe port"

Tags: chromium, node-webkit, ports

I develop a node webkit application that need to display remote resources, like pictures, that way :

```
<img src="http://IP:6000/path/image.png" />
```

=> Picture is not displayed although its address is correct. Node-webkit console doesn't display more information than an empty request in the console.

When I try to display the same picture in Chromium, the following error is displayed in the console :

```
net::ERR_UNSAFE_PORT
```

I think that it is possible that node-webkit has the same ports limitation.
In Chromium, the problem is resolved by passing the following command line parameter :

```
--explicitly-allowed-ports=6000
```

But this command line parameters doesn't seem to be recognized by node-webkit.

Do you have an idea to bypass the problem in node-webkit ?